# What is the correct way to get selected option text using site_prism?

Tags: ruby, capybara, site-prism

I have a [site_prism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism) element that points to a select box. Like this:

```
class MyPageObject < SitePrism::Page
  element :my_select_box, '#select-box-id'
end
```

Although I have a way to get the selected option value, with this:

```
my_page_object.my_select_box.value
```

I cannot find a nice way to get the selected option text. The only workaround that I have found is this:

```
my_page_object.my_select_box.find("option[selected]").text
```

Is there a better way to do that with SitePrism API? Because the above workaround uses a mix of SitePrism and capybara API, which does not seem to be ideal to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never done this, but one way would probably be to define :my_select_box as a section and then have the selected element accessed under that

```
class SelectSection < SitePrism::Section
  element :selected, 'option[selected]'
end

class MyPageObject < SitePrism::Page
  section :my_select_box, SelectSection, '#select-box-id'
end
```

which should let you access

```
my_page_object.my_select_box.selected.text
```

A good question however is why you want to access the text - If it's because you want to verify the text of the selected item against a known text, you're better off actually declaring the element as a select using Capybaras selectors so that you can can use the builtin finder options

```
class MyPageObject < SitePrism::Page
  element :my_select_box, :select, 'select-box-id' # since it's now using Capybaras :select selector it's no longer a css selector so no # in front
end
```

which then should let you do

```
expect(my_page_object).to have_my_select_box(selected: 'the text expected to be selected')
```

Comment: do you know where I can find documentation about the available 'Capybaras selectors', eg, you mentioned above :select, but what is the selector for a link for example, is it :a, or :link or something else?

And when you check the value with SitePrism methods, I had never seen (selected: 'the text ...). Is there more documentation where this 'selected:' or other values, for example for radio buttons, etc is documented.

Comment: @mickael  best place is to look at the Capybara source for the provided selectors - starting at https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L67